# Firebase notification on locked screen does not display on Android

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Firebase notification with React native works perfectly fine in:

- Foreground state
- Background state
- Quit state

The problem occurs when the Android device is on locked screen, The phone vibrates and receives a notification however the screen does not turn on unless I turn it on manually, and there I can see the notification.

The problem is not with the device, since notifications from other apps such as snapchat and instagram, do turn on the screen as well as make a sound when received.

Android.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.app_name">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />



  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground on receiving remote notifications (for prevent duplicating while showing local notifications set this to false) -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground" android:value="false"/>
    <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color" android:resource="@color/white"/>
    <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->

    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" android:exported="true" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" android:exported="true"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:largeHeap="true" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Payload used to trigger notification:

```
{
    "to": "FCM_TOKEN",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Notificatioin Title",
        "body": "Notification Body",
        "sound": "default",
        "android_channel_id": "channel_id",
        "priority": "high"
    },
    "priority": "high",
    "data": {
        "additional_info": ""
    },
    "android":{
      "priority":"high"
    },
    "priority": "high"
}
```

I have tried searching for a way to increase priority of the notification in the payload, but nothing I've tested works.